# Where are Geth's "fast" and "light" syncing options officially documented?

Tags: go-ethereum

Go Ethereum's documentation for running the command line program is at https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options

There it specifies the `--syncmode` option with the explanation:

> Blockchain sync mode ("fast", "full", or "light")

Where are the terms "fast", "full", and "light" specified?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure where exactly it is officially documented, but I recently wrote an article about [***Running an Ethereum Full Node on a RaspberryPi 4 (model B)***](https://kauri.io/article/9695fcca217f46feb355245275835fc0) where I provide in the introduction a summary of the different syncing modes of Geth.

Extract from the article:

> **Blockchain sync mode [`--syncmode`]:**
>
> **`full` sync:** A full sync downloads all the data (block headers and block
>   bodies), processes the entire blockchain one link at a time, and
>   replays all transactions that ever happened in history (transaction
>   processing and PoW verification). This method is the most traditional
>   and stable but can take a very a long time (up to a few weeks) and
>   would require a more powerful machine. At the end of the process, the
>   node is a full node.
>
> **`fast` sync:** A fast sync also downloads all the data (block headers and
>   block bodies) but exchanges processing power for bandwidth usage.
>   Instead of processing all the transactions that ever happened, fast
>   sync downloads all the transaction receipts and the entire recent
>   state database and perform a PoW verification. When the chain reaches
>   a recent state (head - 1024 blocks), geth switches to full sync mode,
>   import the remaining blocks and process them as in the classical sync
>   (full) to obtain a full node.
>
> **`light` sync:** Light mode syncs directly to the last few blocks, does not
>   store the whole blockchain in database. Unlike full and fast, is not a
>   full node as it doesn't store the entire blockchain but only the block
>   headers, and it depends on full nodes. But this approach, less secure
>   and more suitable for IOT/mobiles, only uses 100MB of space.
>
> **Blockchain garbage collection mode [`--gcmode`]**: Garbage collection is
>   used to discard old state tries and save some space.
>
> **`--gcmode full`** enables the garbage collection to keep in memory only the latest 128 tries. This saves a lot of space and it takes less than
>   200 GB at this stage (Sept 2019) to run a full node in this setup.
>
> **`--gcmode archive`** disables the garbage collection and keep all the historical state data blocks after blocks of Ethereum since the
>   Genesis. (bear in mind, it takes more than 2.3 TB of space). But very
>   few people (such as Block Explorers) need an archive node.

Answer (score 0):

They are specified when you run `geth --help` from a command line.

When I run it locally on my PC (with Geth v1.5.7-stable-da2a22c3 installed), I get:

```
--fast     Enable fast syncing through state downloads
--light    Enable light client mode
```

Sorry, apparently this Geth version doesn't support `full`...

Comment: Geth still supports full sync "--syncmode full" (--fast is just an alias of --syncmode fast)

Comment: @GregJeanmart: Yup, guess you're right. I only copied the relevant part provided with `geth --help` (as this user has asked where is the documentation of these options).